# Spring:message, No message found under code for locale 'en_US'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

This is what I have added in my spring-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:application"/>
    </bean>
```

and my **application.properties** file is inside **src/main/resources** folder, but am getting this exception

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [MVC-Dispatcher] in context with path [/MVCLayer] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'Login_Username' for locale 'en_US'.] with root cause
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'Login_Username' for locale 'en_US'.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doEndTag(MessageTag.java:200)
```

Please help on what is wrong with the configuration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `value="application"` if you place your properties file inside the `src/main/resources` folder

And of course make sure that the `application.properties` file contains a line that starts with `Login_Username=`

Comment: hey thanks...that was the mistake i was doing I think...as soon as I removed classpath it worked...thanks :)